# Como mostrar información de una tabla MySql con PHP en otra pagina?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Lo que necesito es que cuando le de clic en una imagen o botón me haga un select de una tabla y los datos de x tabla me los muestre en otra pagina que no sea la misma.

Algún ejemplo?

***Soy nuevo en estos sitios***

----------- ACA HACE LA CONSULTA --------------------

```
<?php
    $sql=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuesto");
    while($res=  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<form action="descripcion.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<div class="col">';
        echo '<figure class="img-border"><a href="descripcion.php"><img src="../Administrador/pages/RepuestoCRUD/'.$res["imagen_repuesto"].'"width="230" heigth="220"></a></figure>';
        echo'<h6>'.$res["nombre_repuesto"].'</h6>';
        echo'<h6>$'.$res["precio_repuesto"].'</h6>';
        echo'<p class="p2">'.$res["descripcion_repuesto"].'</p>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Aceptar">';
        echo'<a class="button" href="descripcion.php">Leer Mas</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
?>
```

--------------------- muestra los datos-------------------

```
/******** CONECTAR CON BASE DE DATOS **************** */ 

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   if (!$con){die('ERROR DE CONEXION CON MYSQL: ' . mysql_error());} 
/* ********************************************** */

/********* CONECTA CON LA BASE DE DATOS  **************** */
   $database = mysql_select_db("sicoa",$con);
   if (!$database){die('ERROR CONEXION CON BD: '.mysql_error());}
/* ********************************************** */

//ejecutamos la consulta
$sql = "SELECT nombre_repuesto, descripcion_repuesto, precio_repuesto FROM repuesto WHERE idrepuesto='"
      .$_POST['idrepuesto']."'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
// verificamos que no haya error 
if (! $result){
   echo "La consulta SQL contiene errores.".mysql_error();
   exit();
}else {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Nombre</td><td>Precio</td><td>Existencia</td>
         </tr><tr>";
//obtenemos los datos resultado de la consulta 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td>
              <td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hola Alexander, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Si eres nuevo en este sitio te invito a que visites esta página: [tour]. También te recomiendo que leas las guías del [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help), en especial, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo la guía [mcve].

Comment: podrías colocar lo que ya hiciste??

Comment: @josego YA PUSE EL CODIGO

Answer (score 2):

> Revisando tu código puedo ver varios detalles:
>
> - Estas usando funciones [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php). **Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0**.
> - Para ir a ver el "detalle" de un repuesto:
>
>   - Tienes 2 `anchors (a)` los que harán una redirección `GET` a `descripcion.php`
>   - Tienes un `formulario (form)` y un `botón (button submit)`, el cual hará una redirección `POST`
>   - Para todos estos, se te ha olvidado incluir el `ID` del repuesto.
> - En `descripcion.php`, al hacer la consulta estas corriendo riesgo de sufrir un [ataque de inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Solución:

Para corregir todo lo anterior, he realizado las siguientes modificaciones:

- Reemplazo de `mysql_*`, por [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
- Enviar el `ID` por `GET`.
- Usamos [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) sobre la variable `GET`, para prevenir la inyección SQL.

Código final:

---- Listado de repuestos ----

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sicoa");
    if (!$con){
        die('ERROR DE CONEXION CON MYSQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $result =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM repuesto");
    while($res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        // Creamos la URL concatenando el ID del repuesto
        $link = 'descripcion.php?id='.$res['idrepuesto'];
?>
    <div class="col">
      <figure class="img-border">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
          <img src="../Administrador/pages/RepuestoCRUD/<?php echo $res["imagen_repuesto"]; ?>" width="230" heigth="220">
        </a>
      </figure>
      <h6><?php echo $res["nombre_repuesto"]; ?></h6>
      <h6>$<?php echo $res["precio_repuesto"]; ?></h6>
      <p class="p2"><?php echo $res["descripcion_repuesto"]; ?></p>
      <a class="button" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Leer Mas</a>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

-- Detalle del repuesto (`descripcion.php`) ---

```
<?php
/******** CONECTAR CON BASE DE DATOS **************** */ 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sicoa");
if (!$con){
    die('ERROR DE CONEXION CON MYSQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
/* ********************************************** */

// Escapamos para prevenir inyeccion SQL
$idrepuesto = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['id']);

// Ejecutamos la consulta
$sql = "SELECT nombre_repuesto, descripcion_repuesto, precio_repuesto 
    FROM repuesto
    WHERE idrepuesto='$idrepuesto'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// verificamos que no haya error 
if (!$result){
    echo "La consulta SQL contiene errores.".mysqli_error($con);
    exit();
} else {
    echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Existencia</td>
      </tr>";

    //obtenemos los datos resultado de la consulta 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row['nombre_repuesto']."</td>
            <td>".$row['precio_repuesto']."</td>
            <td>".$row['descripcion_repuesto']."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```